# WHAT IS THE FX/OIS SPREAD ? WHAT CAN i USE IT FOR?

Tags: fx, ois-swaps

What's an example of fx/ois spread , lets say I am looking at BOE , what spread would I be looking at to see the funding stress or to see if year end turns is trading at a premium or now .

I am on bloomberg.

Comment: It's FXFA on BBG, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76971/54838) for details.

Comment: this isnt clearly explained doe, which why it is confusing . Just needed a simple break down