Fx forward Formula with CBS
I'd like to know how we get the below formula that represents the theoretical pricing of a foreign exchange (FX) forward contract, incorporating adjustments for domestic and foreign interest rates as well as the cross-border spread (CBS).
Pease provide any reference paper for that formula, and how it's used to calibrate Fx forward curve
Thanks


Usually, unless you are a market maker, you just look at quoted FX forwards which are very liquid. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76971/54838 shows how CIP works in detail by replicating FXFA from Bloomberg.

The CIP theory:
If I have 1 EUR today I can (assuming a 1y term to keep notation simple):
a). convert it into USD at a spot rate of $S$ and deposit that money in a USD bank account for 1 year. I will have $S(1+r_{usd})$ at maturity.
b). I can lend this money to an EU bank and earn $(1+r_{eur})$ and convert this at maturity to USD. I can lock that rate in today at an exchange rate of $F$. Giving me $F(1+r_{eur})$ in 1y time.
The two must be equal to preclude arbitrage. Therefore:
$S(1+r_{usd}) = F(1+r_{eur})$, this is also known as the simple covered interest rate parity (sCIP).
The market reality:
In the market what tends to happen, is that despite the above arguments you might still not match the price of quoted forwards. And this has been observed consistently since 2008. Why? As there tends to be an excess demand for 1 currency over another, and the capacity of banks to arbitrage huge international flows is limited, typically participants will pay a premium to get USD funding and this manifests as the "basis". By definition the Xccy basis is precisely the adjustment made (by convention on the non-USD leg of the trade) to allow you to be able to get to the market price of the FX Fwds.
In this case $S(1+r_{usd}) = F(1+r_{eur}+Xccy\_basis)$
So the CIP equation has had to be modified by the addition of this "extra term" the Xccy basis. It is no longer quite so "simple".
