OIS curve, why a multi-curve framework is needed
I don't understand why multi-curve framework is now needed.
Here is my understanding:
The OIS curve is now the curve considered risk-free, and it's used to discount the cashflows for example to value an IRS Swap that pays daily compounded SOFR.
This OIS curve is basically the SOFR curve. So the point at $t$-year is the compounded SOFR from now to $t$-years in the future.
These compounded SOFR term are estimated from Swaps that have annual paying frequency on the fixed leg, and annual paying frequency on the floating and pay daily compounded SOFR on the floating leg. So typically the $1$ Year swap rate will be the compounded SOFR for $1$ Year.
Now to find that curve we just need to solve an optimization problem where we observe the market price of these swaps and try to find the set of compounded SOFR such that our pricing model find the same market price using these compounded SOFR rates.
So why after Libor do we need dual curve building? Here for Swaps we just need one curve, the OIS curve (the SOFR curve).
Whereas during Libor we need two curves, the Libor curve and the discounting curve which is based on a RFR which I guess was EFFR at that time.

@user68819 what is it then? it's the swap rate?

@user68819, SOFR is OIS, and indeed what is used for discounting too. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63748/54838 and for RFR swaps, there is no dual curve stripping. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63631/54838. That said, Euribor for example is still very liquid and most swaptions are still based on Euribor and not ESTR.

quant.stackexchange.com/q/76199/54838 has the description page of a SOFR swap on Bloomberg where you clearly see that it is OIS discounted. The SWPM screenshot shows that the discounting curve is SOFR as well, and the market quote and manual replication are identical.

Yes sorry. I deleted my old comment. What I meant to say is that sofr is not the only ois in US. The FF swap is still quite liquid at the short end, and so too is FF/SOFR basis.
